# Oozie compilation issue

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, oozie

I am trying to install oozie on hadoop1 ..

While compiling :

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [0.372s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... SUCCESS [1.530s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [0.052s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.014s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 1.1.1.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.091s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [0.180s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 Test ........ SUCCESS [0.132s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 2.3.0.oozie-4.0.1 ...... SUCCESS [0.010s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ............ SUCCESS [0.126s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 Test ....... SUCCESS [0.092s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp 0.23.5.oozie-4.0.1 ..... SUCCESS [0.010s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [0.003s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase 0.94.2.oozie-4.0.1 ............. SUCCESS [0.021s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hbase Libs ........................... SUCCESS [0.004s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... FAILURE [0.415s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog 0.6.0.oozie-4.0.1 ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie HCatalog Libs ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ---

-------[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.761s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 23 02:56:46 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/261M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hcatalog:jar:0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:webhcat-java-client:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-serde:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.thrift:libfb303:jar:0.7.0 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-pig-adapter:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.jdo:jdo2-api:jar:2.3-ec: Could not transfer artifact javax.jdo:jdo2-api:pom:2.3-ec from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository.codehaus.org: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project oozie-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-hcatalog:jar:0.5.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:webhcat-java-client:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.hive:hive-serde:jar:0.10.0 (compile), org.apache.thrift:libfb303:jar:0.7.0 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8 (compile), org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-pig-adapter:jar:0.5.0-incubating (compile)]
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some more error stack:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repository.codehaus.org
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1164)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:480)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:746)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:886)
        ... 8 more
```

Can anybody help what is the issue here...

Answer (score 0):

have you update with the hadoop version in the pom.xml,  These is required as in default Oozie builds against Hadoop 1.1.1, so to build against Hadoop 2.4.1, we will have to configure maven dependencies in pom.xml

check this may it helps:
http://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/